# Unix - Count files by modification year

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I am new to UNIX commands. I am trying to list the number of different years of all files in /etc based upon each files modification date(year).

I am playing around with variations of:

ls -lt /etc | sort | uniq -c

I realise that this only counts each unique file. I want to list the different years.

Can anyone help guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mac

```
ls -lT * | awk ' { print $9 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

Linux

```
ls -l --time-style +"%Y" * | awk ' { print $6 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ls -lT * | awk ' { print $9 }' | sort | uniq -c
```